# Using the __str__ method in Django to turn an object into a string - not working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, string, object

I have the following code in models.py, note the function at the bottom that seeks to change the teacher_object in the admin panel to the username of the teacher instead.

```
class Teachers(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    school_pin = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pass_field = models.CharField(db_column='pass', max_length=100)  # Field renamed because it was a Python reserved word.
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    oauth_provider = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    oauth_uid = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    verified = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    verificationcode = models.CharField(db_column='verificationCode', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    membershipid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'teachers'
```

The admin panel still shows the teachers listed as  Teachers object (1275) (and so on).

I have tried the following:
1. Running the makemigrations and migrate commands
2. Logging in and out of the admin panel
3. Refreshing and closing down CMD - restarting

None of the above has worked. There are no errors on running the server. 
Python version: **3.7** Latest Django installation

Considerations:
1. I was using a legacy mysql database so reverse created the models. Could this be affecting anything?
2 I wonder if the class Meta (at the bottom) has any bearing on the error.

I also tried the following, but still no result:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' %(self.username,self.email)
```

For reference, and in case this is relevant here is my admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Teachers
from .models import TeacherPins
admin.site.register(Teachers)
admin.site.register(TeacherPins)
```

Finally, as this is a reverse-generated model (from a legacy mysql) Django provided this advice at the start of the models.py file. Again, could this (not being done, e.g **not having a primary key** etc) have a bearing on the **str** method not working?

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
```

**Update:**

1. I did try rearranging the order (of the classes) - would this make a difference? But still the object remained an object
2. I tried adding a primary key to both classes - this didn't work either

   student_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, primary_key=True)

Comment: you want the `__repr__` method, not `__str__`

Comment: Someone suggested that - it didn't work. Can you explain why? __str__ works perfectly fine in every other app.

Comment: It's in the question: Python 3.7

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with what I have suggested (lack of primary key or perhaps some null value) but I cannot see what to change or how to do it.

Comment: Might it be that the blank=true null=true is causing an error? student_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) ...what does this mean?

Comment: that just means that `student_id` can be `NULL` or "blank" (ie the empty string `''`), I doubt that's doing it

Comment: Your `__str__` method looks ok to me. So the problem could be that you are not running the code you think you are (e.g. you forgot to save/commit/deploy the changes or didn't restart the server. Or there could be a typo you haven't shown e.g. incorrect indentation or misspelled `__str__` (e.g. `___str__`). Or maybe you have imported two `Teachers` classes defined, and you've imported a different one in your `admin.py`.