# Django Project -error in the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, cannot spot error

Tags: django, forms, url, redirect, config

I have looked at previous answers(many are for old versions of Django which doesn't help), but cannot spot the error in my code. I get a 'page not found' error, on running the server, and clicking on the 'submit' button for the form.

The problem appears to be the **redirection**. I don't really understand either the error message (see below) or how it works, so an explanation would help.

```
The current path, addMessage/worldguestbook/worldguestbook.html
```

The relevant **views.py code** and function**

```
def addMessage(request):
    new_item =GuestBookItem(content=request.POST['content'])
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('worldguestbook/worldguestbook.html')
```

**the form (in the html)**

```
<form action="/addMessage/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="content"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add"/>
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('worldguestbook/',worldguestbookView),
    path('login/',loginView),
    path('addMessage/',addMessage),
    ]
```

**Error 1**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addMessage/worldguestbook/worldguestbook.html
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
worldguestbook/
login/
addMessage/
The current path, addMessage/worldguestbook/worldguestbook.html, didn't match any of these.
```

**Note:** The content is actually submitted, but it doesn't redirect correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing redirecting with rendering. You render a template, but you need to redirect to a URL. What URL do you want to redirect to? As the error points out, it needs to be one of those in your urls.py.

For example:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/worldguestbook/')
```

Even better, you should give your URL patterns names and use those names with the `reverse` or `redirect` shortcuts.

Comment: Daniel - thank you so much for your quick response and yes you're quite right, I was confusing rendering with redirecting - copying the code from the first view. So, your suggestion works! Can you explain why the slashes on either side - that I don't get.

Comment: Also, you appear to be a Django genius. No one could quite answer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658454/using-the-str-method-in-django-to-turn-an-object-into-a-string-not-working/55659337#55659337